# Prevent anyone from accessing my bucket unless a certain condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an ec2 instance with a load balancer and cloudfront attached and I want to prevent my s3 bucket files from being viewed unless the files are being requested on my website. How would I be able to do this? I've tried "referrer" (which doesn't work sometimes, and apprently not the best option) and I've tried using the "source ip" condition which just doesn't work, I've put in my website ip, my vpc ip from my load balancer, etc, just doesn't work (unless there's another way I have to do it, I would appreciate it if anyone told me). I just want a bucket policty that has a condition like so:

```
            "Condition": {
 ** person is on my website **
                }
```

If anyone has any ideas, that would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can immediately think of 2 options:

1. Make your bucket private and instead reverse-proxy the images through your own website.
2. Make your bucket use [Query String Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) and have your website generate a short-lived QSA token (5 minutes?) for each visitor.

Comment: What do you mean by reverse proxy? Also I already am doing the second option, but I want to add more to it because someone can just inspect and open the source in a new tab and then download from there.

Comment: @TedBed The files exist on S3, but they're accessed via HTTP requests to your website, not S3. (so your own website makes a child request to S3 and forwards the response to your website visitor)

Comment: So would this be able to prevent people from downloading the files, as this is my main goal.

Comment: To be more clear, to make it more difficult for one to download the file.

Comment: @TedBed **You cannot prevent people from downloading anything on the web** - but by using a QSA with a short expiration (10 seconds, perhaps?) means that your visitors won't be able to make a second request after the page has already loaded. Of course they could always just view their browsers' cache and extract files from there.

Comment: Sorry for another comment, but according to a reddit post, it looks like using cloudfront as a delivery service counts as reverse proxy: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6ev20f/reverse_proxy_in_front_of_s3_bucket/  --- which is what I'm already doing. Does that count as reverse proxy?

Comment: @TedBed In a general broad-sense, yes - but in this case I meant implementing the RP functionality directly in your own website (nothing to do with CloudFront at all) as that way you can implement your own custom access-control rules (such as requiring an active session cookie, for example) which you can't do with CloudFront.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll probably take a look into encrypting files as well instead to make it more difficult as someone could just look in their browser cache like you said. Thank you very much. However I still would've like to know what kind of bucket policy I could use to prevent people who aren't viewing files on my site from accessing them because it seems unprofessional if one could just check the source file and download it from there. I've already figured out that with cloudfront, if you try directly downloading the file by right clicking and pressing "Save As" it will say that it is forbidden.

Comment: If the files are encrypted then they can't be used in a web-browser...

Comment: "I've already figured out that with cloudfront, if you try directly downloading the file by right clicking and pressing "Save As" it will say that it is forbidden" - I assume that's using a `Referer`-policy? If so, then that's not going to work with ultramodern and privacy-protecting web-browsers that don't send `Referer` at all (as those users will be blocked as well). Please don't be hostile to your users. What makes you think your content or files is so valuable that it's worth degrading your website's UX?

Comment: I don't have to use a referer policy, I know that there are other options like how people use sourceip policy for cloudflare.

Comment: Also I was refering to encrypting video and audio files, because those can be decrypted (I believe) and then played on web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If your content is being served from Amazon S3 or Amazon CloudFront, you can use **pre-signed URLs** to grant time-limited access to private content.

For example, let's say that you have a photo-sharing website and all photos are private by default. Access can be provided as follows:

- Users **authenticate** to your application
- The user then requests access to a private object, or your application wishes to generate an HTML page that includes a link to a private object (eg in an `<img>` tag).
- The application checks whether the user is permitted to access the object. If they are, the application **generates a pre-signed URL** and provides it in the HTML page or as a link.
- The user's browser then uses the URL to request the private object, which sends the request to CloudFront or S3
- CloudFront or S3 then checks whether the pre-signed URL is correctly signed and is still within the validity period. If so, it provides access to the object. If not, it returns `Access Denied`.

For more information, see:

- [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)
- [Using Amazon CloudFront Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html)